# Transform line equation in one co-ordinate system X'Y'Z' into XYZ

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I have a Straight Line of the form:

$\begin{pmatrix}
P_{x'}\\
P_{y'}\\
P_{z'}\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{0}\\
B_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1}\\
B_{1}\\
1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot z'$

where those two vectors can be assigned the terms position and direction vectors.

I want to transform this line back into XYZ frame.

I know how the X'Y'Z' frame is related to the XYZ frame by the matrix M, were M=

$\begin{pmatrix}
X'\cdot x & Y' \cdot x & Z'\cdot x\\
X' \cdot y & Y' \cdot y & Z' \cdot y\\
X' \cdot z & Y' \cdot z & Z' \cdot z\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Such that a position in X'Y'Z' is transformed to XYZ via:

$\vec{P}_{xyz} = \underline{\underline{M}} \cdot \vec{P}_{X'Y'Z'} $

I get how to do this for a position vector but how do I deal with the direction part?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You need to know how the frames are related. In other words, what type of transformation are you talking about, for there are infinitely many.

Comment: What’s tripping you up? The fact that the parameter happens to be named $z'$? Call it something else, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtlety you are missing: $z^\prime$ is a parameter. The line is formed by varying $z^\prime$.

So, parameterize the line more generally as a vector-valued function of some parameter, $t \in \{-\infty,+\infty\}$. Then $\mathbf{P} \equiv \mathbf{P}(t)$ which can be represented in the primed basis as $\mathbf{P}(t) = x^\prime(t)\mathbf{x^\prime} + y^\prime(t)\mathbf{y^\prime} + z^\prime(t)\mathbf{y^\prime}$ . Let $z^\prime(t) = t$, so that $x^\prime(t) = A_0 + A_1t$, $y^\prime(t) = B_0 + B_1t$, and $z^\prime(t) = t$. Now, if you know the transformation $(x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime) \rightarrow (x,y,z)$, all you have to do is apply is to $(x^\prime(t),y^\prime(t),z^\prime(t))$ to obtain $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$, which will have a similar form ($x(t) = a_0 + a_1t$, $y(t) = b_0 + b_1t$, and $z(t) = c_0 + c_1t$), which you can write in a similar form as the equation you have above in the primed basis.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
P_{x}\\
P_{y}\\
P_{z}\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{0}\\
b_{0}\\
c_{0}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}\\
b_{1}\\
c_{1}
\end{pmatrix} t
$$

Comment: To clarify, since you get how to transform a position vector, once you parameterize the line, you are simply applying the transformation to a bunch of different position vectors, each one associated with a value of $t$.  No need to explicitly think about "dealing with the direction part".

Comment: Hi, thanks yes this is what I thought but then I became confussed because the parameter t is still the primed co-ordinate z' - would I need to do another transform on there to be able to visualize this in purely unprimed co-ordinate system. This is basically the end result from a fitting routine. The fit is done in the prime system which is local to a given track and I want to then translate the fit result into the world (unprimed) system to compare with a Monte Carlo value to prove how well the fit has been done. That MC would be in XYZ frame.

Comment: If you have the transformation matrix $\underline{\underline{M}}$, and you have the parameterized line in the primed coordinate system, $\vec{P}_{X'Y'Z'}(t)$, then you should simply carry out matrix multiplication, as you have written in the question.  $$\vec{P}_{xyz}(t) = \underline{\underline{M}} \vec{P}_{X'Y'Z'}(t)$$.

Comment: And theres no need to convert from the parameter being the z' to being z? this is what I am confussed about as the z' is a local co-ordinate and doesnt mean anything in the unprimed system. Realistically I would want the parameter to be changed to a z.....so I can transform using this equationbut would still have t=z' and to make t=z...is there any easy way to do that? Given I know the relationship between the Z' axis and the XYZ axes

Comment: If I understand correctly, I believe you could achieve what you want in the following way. Proceed as above, obtaining $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ in the unprimed basis.  Then, invert the equation for $z(t)$ to obtain $t(z) = z^{-1}(z(t))$.  Then replace $(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \rightarrow (x(t(z)),y(t(z)),z(t(z))) = (x(z),y(z),z))$.

Comment: The line is already parameterized “as a vector-valued function of some parameter.” That this parameter happens to be called $z'$ is immaterial. Even if were named $t$ or something else innocuous, the parameterization could still be described as forming the line by varying $z'$.